# Magento Guest Checkout to PayPal and No Address Details?

Tags: magento, paypal

trying to configure Magento 1.9 to only have Checkout As Guest and therefore hide the other accordion options such as Billing Address and Shipping Information, as I want them only to pay through PayPal. Also hide all references to registered user accounts and register / login to account options.
Is this possible please?

Many thanks for any help,

Barton.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Magento uses PHP and XML to configure and make bespoke design changes, plus the Template changes to. Thanks your concern.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it does, but you did not specifically ask for a programmatic solution. It sounded like you're asking to configure an extension. I would suggest that you edit the question to include the code you need help with. I'll be glad to reopen the question if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure PayPal Express Checkout as your payment method. That way customers can skip the checkout and go directly to PayPal.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I was thinking which version of PayPal would fit the bill.